# Chrome web browser display issues

Tags: google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, website

[image]

Of late I have been experiencing problems with Chrome web browser in displaying websites.

I have had this with `Facebook` and one news site I can not recall. I tried clearing the cache and temp file but the problem persists.

**What is causing this ? How to solve this ?**

I do not have problems with any Stack site. Also, there are problems with IE displaying FB.

Comment: If you refresh the pages you are having troubles with, do they load correctly?

Comment: @Alex troubles.

Comment: Typically this will happen if something is blocking your Internet connection, such as a proxy or content filter.  It looks as though the page is having troubles loading the `.css` files necessary to properly lay-out that page.